# What is the best way to store data locally ( IOS - xcode )

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data, local-database

I've designed an IOS app and it's working fine so far , the next step I want to do is loading default data to my app which are ( texts and images ) , but I don't know how to do that ?

I don't know the best way to do it and there are many choices . Plist , sqlite , core data .

To give a clear idea about my app :
It contains many categories and I want to store default data in each category , one of the category contains images and the rest contain texts .

The data is a default, I don't want the user to change it , and I want to store the data manually ( by me ) because every tutorial I've watched , the data was stored by the user .

So , I need to know the best way to do that and how to store data manually . I think The best approach so far by using Sqlite .

Comment: Hi, this article might help you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1

Comment: Thank you this definitely will help , I found this awesome tutorial ( https://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated ) but it is old and using objective-c .. I hope there is a tutorial like this for swift .

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Data for storing any data that is beyond just user preferences.

Do not store images or other binary values in Core Data directly.  There are plenty of discussions on here as to why.

Use SQLite as the store for Core Data.

Comment: So , I can store store data in sqlite then adding it to core data ? Or using core data to store data in sqlite ??

Comment: You use Core Data in your application.  You configure Core Data to use SQLite as the persistence file on disk.